# Issue with angular factory service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to get my head round Angular services. I've created a simple example but when I try to utilize the service the console spits out an error (see below)

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

service.js

```
myApp.factory('Addition', function() {
  return {
    plusOne: function() {
      $scope.number += 1;
    }
  };
})
```

UserController.js

```
myApp.controller( 'UserCtrl', [ '$scope', 'Addition', function($scope, Addition ) {

  $scope.number = 0;

  $scope.plusOne = Addition.plusOne();

}]);
```

view.html

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
     {{number}}

  <button ng-click=plusOne()></button>

</div>
```

The view displays `$scope.number` correctly until I add `$scope.plusOne = Addition.plusOne();` and the console spits out

> ReferenceError: $scope is not defined at Object.plusOne

I'm probably missing something fairly fundamental here but would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can not inject `$scope` dependency inside service, `service/factory` are singleton object which are there to share data between component of angular module.

Do change the implementation to below would work for you.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
     {{getPlusOneValue()}}
  <button ng-click=plusOne()></button>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
myApp.factory('Addition', function() {
  var number = 0;
  return {
    plusOne: function() {
      number += 1;
    },
    //plus one getter
    getPlusOneValue: function(){
       return number;
    }
  };
})
```

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller( 'UserCtrl', [ '$scope', 'Addition', 
   function($scope, Addition ) {
      $scope.plusOne = Addition.plusOne;
      $scope.getPlusOneValue = Addition.getPlusOneValue;
   }
]);
```

Comment: @dellboyant Pleased to know that.. Do accept answer..once you able to do it..Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Better to do like this. Because "{{getPlusOneValue()}}" function will be fired in all angular digest cycle which we don't need.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl" ng-bind="number">
  <button ng-click=plusOne()></button>
</div>
```

**Factory**

```
myApp.factory('Addition', function() {
  var number = 0;
  return {
    //plus one getter
    getPlusOneValue: function(){
       return ++number;
    }
  };
})
```

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller( 'UserCtrl', [ '$scope', 'Addition', 
   function($scope, Addition ) {
      $scope.number = '';
      $scope.plusOne = function () {
        $scope.number = Addition.getPlusOneValue();
      }
   }
]);
```